Is my understanding/approach to nested cross-validation, final model tuning correct?
I am training a SVM on limited training data with unbalanced classes.
Here are the things that I want to do:
1.) I want to make a statement of the generalizability of the approach to different independent training and testing datasets.
2.) I want to train a final model for production.
For 1.), my understanding is that I would do nested cross-validation.
This is my approach which I have hobbled together from various sources, just hoping to get feedback on if anything here is egregiously wrong:
# the SVM parameters I want to try in optimization
parameters_svm = {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear'], 'probability': [True]}



# define the inner and outer cv  
# here I picked `n_splits=5` for the inner cv and `n_splits=10` for the outer cv because of this https://machinelearningmastery.com/nested-cross-validation-for-machine-learning-with-python/
# I decided to use StratifiedKFold here for the inner cv because the class imbalance 
# I decided to use RepeatedStratifiedKFold with n_repeats=10 in the outer cv because it will run in a reasonable amount of time and because it seems to make sense that you would want to get a performance number based on many iterations.


inner_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,random_state=42, shuffle=True)
outer_cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=10, random_state=42)




# Run nested cross-validation and compute the outer score (generalization error)
nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=nX, y=y, cv=outer_cv, scoring='balanced_accuracy')

print(f'Nested CV Balanced Accuracy: {nested_scores.mean()} +/- {nested_scores.std()}')

For 2.), I am a little less sure here and I have seen some discussion about leveraging the set of hyperparamters that performed best most often in nested CV but based on this link I would do one loop of the outer loop, eg:
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=SVC(), param_grid=parameters_svm, cv=outer_cv, scoring='balanced_accuracy')
grid.fit(X, y)

# get the best params
best_params = grid.best_estimator_.get_params()

Does this all make sense or am I way off base?


I want to make a statement of the generalizability of the approach to different independent training and testing datasets [...] my understanding is that I would do nested cross-validation.

I think that would work. Nested CV says 'tuned SVCs score X% on average on test data'. It doesn't specify any particular tuned SVC, but rather on average how well a tuned model performs on test samples from your data.

This is my approach which I have hobbled together from various sources, just hoping to get feedback on [...]

Nested CV is often used to compare different types of models, and thus is a high-level tuning strategy. That being the case, one would usually need to split off a test set that never gets used in CV. The test set would only be used at the very end to measure the final model.
In your case, however, it seems like you are not using nested CV for any model selection, so using all of the data sounds okay. If you have used this same data in prior steps for selecting an SVC, then the test scores won't be unbiased measures.

parameters_svm = {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear'], 'probability': [True]}

If you don't need the probabilities (not required for "balanced_accuracy"), and are using the "linear" kernel, then LinearSVC() is a more efficient model to use here.
SVMs require features to be scaled, which ought to be done independently for each fold. In other words, I expect your clf is a pipeline like:
clf_pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVC(...))

You can then wrap that in a CV tuner to get the inner CV estimator:
clf_tuner = GridSearchCV(clf_pipeline, param_grid, ...)

You might already be doing something similar though.

I am training a SVM on limited training data with unbalanced classes.

SVC also has a class_weight= option that you can set to "balanced" to penalise classes equally, otherwise the more frequent ones might dominate the optimisation process.

I decided to use RepeatedStratifiedKFold with n_repeats=10 in the outer cv because it will run in a reasonable amount of time and because it seems to make sense that you would want to get a performance number based on many iterations.

You could probably get away with fewer repeats (and fewer outer folds) if you wanted shorter runtimes. Repeats might help you get a more stable CV average than a single run, but they don't make the average itself more accurate (see this study).

2.) I want to train a final model for production.

The code snippet you've included for that part runs 100-fold CV, which is 100 evaluations for each hyperparameter. It'll work, but might not be necessary. You might find the same optimal hyperparameters using fewer folds like cv=5 or cv=10.
The nested CV tells you how a tuned model would perform on average, but if you wanted a test score specifically for the final model, you'd need a test set.

Example data and code showing nested CV for a pipelined SVC.

Best pipeline's validation score is 0.966 | C= 0.14

Imports and data:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Data for testing
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True, n_class=10)

Nested CV:
from sklearn.model_selection import (
    StratifiedKFold,
    RepeatedStratifiedKFold,
    GridSearchCV,
    cross_val_score,
    train_test_split
)
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

#For building a pipeline where data is appropriately scaled, per CV fold
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


#Split off a test set - this will only be used at the end for assessing the final model
cv_ixs, test_ixs = train_test_split(
    range(len(X)), stratify=y, shuffle=True, random_state=0, test_size=0.1
)

X_cv, y_cv = [arr[cv_ixs] for arr in [X, y]]
X_test, y_test = [arr[test_ixs] for arr in [X, y]]

n_inner_splits = 3
n_outer_splits = 10
n_repeats = 3
inner_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_inner_splits, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
outer_cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_outer_splits, n_repeats=n_repeats, random_state=0)

param_grid = {
    'linearsvc__C': np.logspace(-3, 4), #same as [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, ..., 10_000]
}

pipeline = make_pipeline(
    StandardScaler(),
    LinearSVC(class_weight='balanced', dual='auto', max_iter=5_000, tol=1e-2)
)

pipeline_tuner = GridSearchCV(
    pipeline,
    param_grid,
    cv=inner_cv,
    scoring='balanced_accuracy', #specify metric to tune for
    n_jobs=-1,
)

# Run nested cross-validation and compute the outer score (generalization error)
nested_scores = cross_val_score(
    pipeline_tuner, X_cv, y_cv,
    cv=outer_cv,
    scoring='balanced_accuracy',
)

View results:
#View nested scores across the n_outer_splits folds, for each repeat
nested_scores = nested_scores.reshape(n_repeats, n_outer_splits)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 2))

for repeat in range(1, n_repeats + 1):
    x_jitter = np.random.randn(n_outer_splits) / 9
    ax.scatter(
        np.full(n_outer_splits, fill_value=repeat) + x_jitter,
        nested_scores[repeat - 1],
        marker='d',
        s=25,
        edgecolor='black',
    )

ax.set_xticks(range(1, n_repeats + 1))
ax.set(
    xlabel='repeat',
    ylabel='balanced accuracy',
    title=f'Nested CV scores | {nested_scores.mean():.2f}$\pm${nested_scores.std():.2f}'
)
ax.spines[['right', 'top']].set_visible(False)
ax.spines.bottom.set_bounds(1, n_repeats)
ax.set_ylim(0.92, 1)

Tune, fit, and report a final model:
#Use the smaller CV for tuning the final model (you could use the other cv too)
np.random.seed(0)
best_pipeline = pipeline_tuner.fit(X_cv, y_cv, refit=True).best_estimator_

# get the best params
print(
    "Best pipeline's validation score is",
    pipeline_tuner.best_score_.round(3),
    '| C=',
    best_pipeline['linearsvc'].C.round(2)
)

#Final test score - for the deployed model. Not for tuning.
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score

print(
    'Test score for deployed pipeline is',
    # balanced_accuracy_score(y_test, best_pipeline.predict(X_test)).round(3)
)

